# Web-Scraping with LUA

Tags: html, xpath, lua

I am trying to build a web-scraper in Lua. It will act as an extension to the MoneyMoney App on OSX.

Here is what I am doing to log into the site:

```
  local request = connection:request(loginPage:xpath("//*[@id='loginForm_submit']"):click())
  overview_html = HTML(request)
```

When authentication is successful, the ID of the HTML body will be "portfolio", otherwise it will be "login" (for a new attempt).

I am trying to evaluate this as follows

```
  local login = overview_html:xpath("//*[@id='login']")
  if login.length() > 0 then
    return LoginFailed
  end
```

But I get the following error when executing:

> kiva-extension.lua:42: bad argument #1 to 'length' (table expected,
>   got no value)

Line 42 is the "login.length > 0" check.

As I am very new to both LUA and XPATH any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: try `login:length()`

Comment: That was actually it!
Such a simple mistake. Having dealt with Python recently, I thought it would be a dot but it is not. Need to get my eyes checked 8-)

Answer (score 1):

From comments: The solution here was to use `login:length()` instead of `login.length()` (notice `:` vs. `.`).